# Typegoose can't output array with findOne

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongodb, mongoose, typegoose

I trying to take back my TelegramEntity from MongoDB and can't retrieve array with **adverts**. What can I do to fix this problem?

telegram.entity.ts:

```
import { prop, getModelForClass, modelOptions } from "@typegoose/typegoose";

export class AdvertSubscriptionEntity {
  @prop({ type: String, required: true, select: true })
  public location!: string;

  @prop({ type: Boolean })
  public lessOrEqual?: boolean;

  @prop({ type: Number })
  public price?: number;

  @prop({ type: Boolean, default: true })
  public active?: boolean;

  constructor(opts?: Partial<AdvertSubscriptionEntity>) {
    if (opts) {
      Object.assign(this, opts);
    }
  }
}

@modelOptions({ schemaOptions: { collection: "telegrams" } })
export class TelegramEntity {
  @prop({ type: String })
  public username?: string;

  @prop({ type: Number, required: true })
  public chatId!: number;

  @prop({
    type: () => [AdvertSubscriptionEntity],
    _id: false,
    select: true
  })
  public adverts?: AdvertSubscriptionEntity[];
}

export const TelegramModel = getModelForClass(TelegramEntity);
```

Here is how I find my tg row:

```
return await TelegramModel
      .findOne(filter, undefined, options)
      .exec();
```

So in result: `{"_id":"<ObjectId>","username":"<username>","chatId": <id> ,"__v":0}`

My package.json:

```
"@typegoose/typegoose": "8.2",
"mongoose": "6",
```

Comment: It's strange because in tests official rep it just works - https://github.com/typegoose/typegoose/blob/master/test/tests/biguser.test.ts#L59

Comment: mongoose 6.0 is not supported below typegoose 9.0 (which currently still is in beta), see https://typegoose.github.io/typegoose/docs/guides/mongoose-compatibility/

Comment: could you also provide what your `options` for `findOne` are? also, if your issue still exists after using the correct typegoose-mongoose combination, could you open up a issue in the typegoose repository with providing the [debug log](https://typegoose.github.io/typegoose/docs/guides/advanced/logger/#enable-debug-logger)?

Answer (score 0):

I change adverts type from `[AdvertSubscriptionEntity]` to `mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed` and my code works.